# Как узнать конец строки в виджете Text?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно как-то узнать текст всей строки по её индексу. Вот, что у меня сейчас есть

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x150")

inputText = Text(height=5)
inputText.pack()

def showInfo():
    print("Курсор на:", inputText.index("insert")) #Вывод позиции курсора
    print("Текст со всей строки:",  ???) #Я не знаю, что тут делать
    try:
        print("Selected text:", inputText.get('sel.first', 'sel.last')) #Вывод выделеного текста
    except:
        pass

button = Button(text="Узнать информацию", command=showInfo) #Кнопка
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Допустим у меня на курсоре вывелось 2.4. Я хочу узнать как сделать, чтобы вывелся весь текст из второй строки.
Искал в интернете - ничего не нашел. Решил написать сюда, спасибо наперед

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения текста со всей строки нужно получить текст из диапазона от `"1.0"` до `"1.end"` (1 - для первой строки, нужно заменить на фактический номер строки).

Поэтому сначала нужно получить номер строки, где находится курсор, из `inputText.index("insert")`, потом подставить его в индексы, и получить текст из диапазона между этими индексами:

```
line_number = inputText.index("insert").partition(".")[0]  # "123.45" -> "123"
print("Текст со всей строки:", inputText.get(f"{line_number}.0", f"{line_number}.end"))
```

[image: Скриншот]